# Woocommerce - Add Coupon is not deducting totals

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating my order like so:

```
$order = wc_create_order();

$product = wc_get_product( $_POST["product"] );
$order->add_product( $product, 1 );

$kupon = new WC_Coupon( $_POST["coupon"] );
$amount = $kupon->get_discount_amount( $product->price );
$order->add_coupon( $_POST["coupon"], $amount, $amount );

$order->calculate_shipping();
$order->calculate_totals();
```

If you take a closer look, I am adding a coupon code dynamicaly with add_coupon function from WC_Order class. Everythings works perfectly, the order is added to database with correct product, quantites, and ALSO the coupon is added  - but the problem is that coupon is not "applied" to the total. It is not **deducting the totals price**. Here is the image:
[image]

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: I am also having the same problem :( I tried in many ways, but didn't find a solution. Anybody got the answer?

Comment: I got it solved by passing an argument while adding a product to an order like this: $args = array(
    "totals" => array('subtotal' => $price,
          'total' => $price - $coupon_discount)
   );
      $order->add_product( $product, 1, $args);

Comment: @ShwethaU I believe you should post your answer as it will help other people. :D Anyway thanks for the info.

Comment: Sure ;) I will post it as answer..

Comment: I'm experiencing this too. The solution ShwethaU suggests feels kinda hacky. Did you ever solve this another way?

Answer (score 4):

While adding a product to an Order, we should pass an argument containing subtotal and total like this:

```
$args = array(
    "totals" => array('subtotal' => $item["price"],
                      'total' => $item["price"] - $coupon_discount)
);                      
$order->add_product( $product, 1, $args);
```

Where `$product` is Woocommerce product. Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked in my case for modifying order line items then applying a discount afterward - $order is a WC_Order object:

```
    $order_total        = $order->get_total()
    $coupon_code        = $this->get_coupon_code( $order );
    $coupon             = new WC_Coupon( $coupon_code );
    $coupon_type        = $coupon->discount_type;
    $coupon_amount      = $coupon->coupon_amount;
    $final_discount     = 0;

    // You must calculate the discount yourself! I have not found a convenient method outside the WC_Cart context to do this for you.
    $final_discount = $coupon_amount * ( $order_total / 100 );

    $order->add_coupon( $coupon_code, $final_discount, 0 );
    $order->set_total( $final_discount );
```

Here is the method to retrieve the coupon code for a WC_Order object. In my case I know there will never be more then 1 coupon per order so you may want to adjust it to accommodate more:

```
public function get_coupon_code( $subscription ) {

    $coupon_used = '';
    if( $subscription->get_used_coupons() ) {

      $coupons_count = count( $subscription->get_used_coupons() );

      foreach( $subscription->get_used_coupons() as $coupon) {
        $coupon_used = $coupon;
        break;
      } 
    }

    if ( $coupon_used !== '' ) {
        return $coupon_used;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```